# Sybase PowerDesigner 12.1 characters getting corrupted in pdm file

Tags: xml, svn, character-encoding, powerdesigner

A Sybase PowerDesigner 12.1 pdm file is used to store and revision the database model in SVN.

It happens from time to time, that characters get corrupted for some reason when editing the model in PowerDesigner.

The strange thing is that not all characters but some, and not all instances of that character. For example a character 'á' or 'é' gets corrupted and becomes �� for no reason. We are using native language words in the model. I've tried researching how character encoding works in Powerdesigner, but without any success. I couldn't find the related settings.

Any help is appreciated.

The header of the pdm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?PowerDesigner AppLocale="UTF16" ID="{******-***-****-***-****}" Label="label" Name="name" Objects="22446" Symbols="3771" Target="ORACLE Version 10g" Type="{******-***-****-***-****}" signature="PDM_DATA_MODEL_XML" version="12.1.0.1913"?>
```

Comment: I don't understand from your description, if the file is corrupted during edition by PowerDesigner, or when stored in your SVN. The second line mentions that the file is stored (by PowerDesigner) as UTF-16. Is your SVN (and any file type set on the model file) compatible with this kind of file?

Comment: I updated my post to clarify the corruption location. I think the xml file is actually encoded in UTF-8, I don't know why the two encodings differ from each other in the header, thats what is confusing me too. Please clarify what do you mean by "any file type set on the model file". I have set the mime type to text for the file extension .pdm. Thank you.